# Better scrolling performance when site is placed inside an iframe in Firefox on Android

Tags: android, jquery, performance, firefox, iframe

I was playing around with some parallax scrolling techniques and was trying to make the scrolling smooth in mobile browsers that doesn't run on Webkit. Then I suddenly realized that if I take a simple site with some jQuery like this and put it in an iframe it will scroll really smooth in Firefox 23.0 for Android(4.2.2) compare to if I would run the original page as is.

```
$w = $(window);
$object = $('#parallaxscrollobject');

$w.scroll(function(){
    $st = $w.scrollTop() / 5;
    $st2 = $st + 250;
    $object.css('top',$st2);
    $object.css('left',$st);
});
```

Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sandstedt/vb4za/).

[No-iframe original site](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sandstedt/vb4za/show/)

[The iframe version](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sandstedt/aKzVY/1/show/)

Can anyone explain why this performance boost occurs?